# How to upload a file in django and associate this file with the user who uploaded it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building a site that the user login himself/herself and then, upload a file that will be stored to be used later by the user.

My model.py is:

```
class Ontology(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(default="", validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Ontology

class UploadOntologyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ontology
        fields = ('file',)
```

in views.py I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UploadOntologyForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .handle_upload_owl import *

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadOntologyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if not handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']):
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/ontology/')
    else:
        form = UploadOntologyForm()


    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

and latter handle_upload_owl.py

```
def handle_uploaded_file(thisFile):
    if thisFile._size > 5242880:
       return False
    else:
       with open('media/' + str(thisFile), 'wb+') as destination:
           for chunk in thisFile.chunks():
               destination.write(chunk)
       return True
```

edit: Added CustomUser Class

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    institution = models.TextField(max_length=254)
```

My app is loading and storing files correctly, but no entries in database is added, not even related to the logged user who uploaded it.

I'm newbie with django and I'm not dealing well with this. What's wrong?

Comment: Show your `CustomUser` class

Comment: done. customUser is an overrided allauth user class. created to include the insitution field.

Comment: I don't know  how does work allauth, because i didn't work with it. But you can save your user through `request`. `user= request.user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I do not understand why you put a 'not' in
`if not handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])`

Also, you should define a clean method in your form in order to do the checks, instead of making another file:

```
class UploadOntologyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ontology
        fields = ('file',)

    def clean_file(self):
        file= self.cleaned_data['file']

        try:
            #validate content type
            main, sub = file.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG or PNG image.')

            #validate file size
            if len(file) > (10000 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'File size may not exceed 10M.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return file
```

Finally, your index view becomes:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadOntologyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ontology= form.save(commit=False)
            # commit=False tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet, I have more things I want to do with it."
            ontology.name = "Whatever name"
            ontology.user = request.user # Set the user object here
            ontology.save() # Now you can send it to DB
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ontology/')
    else:
        form = UploadOntologyForm()


    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: great answer! Also thanks for the tips. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

`forms.py`:

```
class UploadOntologyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ontology
        fields = ('file',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Here we get our 'req' object. passed from the 
        # construction of this form in views.py
        self.request = kwargs.pop("req")
        # that's all. then we continue the init logic with super.
        super(UploadOntologyForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        # At this point data is processed and 'cleaned'
        data = self.cleaned_data

        # We construct our Ontology with the file and user
        o = Ontology(
            user = self.request.user,
            file =  data['file'])
        # And finally save it!
        o.save()
```

And your updated `views.py` (The call to `UploadOntologyForm` changed ):
    def index(request)

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadOntologyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, req=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            if not handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']):
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/ontology/')
    else:
        form = UploadOntologyForm(req=request)


    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I like @Yom86 [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41069655/6622232) better. Like, not override the form model to be dependent to request, and do it in the `if form.is_valid():` block.